# Class instantiation inside EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, reflection, intellij-idea, ejb

Does the following code violate the EJB 3 specifiation? If so, what can I do about it to retain the desired functionality?

The reason why I'm asking is that IntelliJ 14 produces these warnings:

- Usage of "java.lang.reflect.Constructor" is not allowed in EJB
- Usage of "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" is not allowed in
  EJB

The class(es) I want to instantiate is no EJB, just a POJO, and the EJB serves as a repository for these POJO's (they are encapsulating business logic).

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    public SomeInterface createSomeClass(final Class<? extends AbstractSomeClass> someClass, final MyArgument argument) {
        try {
            final Constructor constructor = someClass.getDeclaredConstructor(argument.getClass());
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return (SomeInterface) constructor.newInstance(state);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO fix exception handling
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Simon

**Edit**

It seems to me that there is a section in the EJB 3 specification that answers the first part of my question:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to query a class to obtain information about the declared
>   members that are not otherwise accessible to the enterprise bean because of the security rules
>   of the Java language. The enterprise bean must not attempt to use the Reflection API to access
>   information that the security rules of the Java programming language make unavailable.

I've never heard of this before and don't understand the reason behind this rule. Stateful EJB's might be an alternative for my problem but that is too heavy-weight for my taste.

Comment: Have you looked at CDI? Seems perfect fit for what you seem to be trying to achieve (producers, injection in constructors, etc).

Comment: I guess that would work but currently I can't introduce CDI because of project restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paragraph is really just a heavy-handed restatement of the minimum Java 2 Security Policy for the EJBs (section 16.3 of the EJB 3.2 spec).  The spec does not guarantee that your EJB will have permission to do what it does.  If you don't have Java 2 security enabled in your application server or you have granted your EJB permission to do that, then you should be fine.  (Of course, the normal caveats for inspecting/changing the state of objects you don't own still apply.)

If you want to avoid the warning anyway, then an alternative might be to create a factory interface:

```
interface AbstractSomeClassFactory<T> { T create(MyArgument a); }
```

...and pass that to the EJB instead.  I don't have any other great ideas.

Comment: Very useful, thank you. The factory does not need to be an EJB, of course!